# Destroy $_session on website by pressing home button on iphone

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, session

I need to destroy an user session in php when the navigator is closed. My script works fine but not for iPhone or other devices when the home button is pressed to close the navigator.

Comment: You don't know, when the user clicks the home button. PHP is server-side. After the request is made, you have no connection the the browser, so PHP is not the answer, maybe Javascript is, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Phones generally suspend (vs. close) the browser when you leave the app. You may be able to destroy the session after a timeout by setting a low session.gc_maxlifetime and have some clientside js ping the server every now and then to keep the session open while the app is not suspended. YMMV.

You could also investigate the window.onbeforeunload event to see if that is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) to trigger an AJAX call?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "path/to/script.php",
       async: false
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i've allready tried the onbeforeunload event but dont works with the "suspend" ..